# How to represent C++ new() operator using UML

Tags: c++, uml, new-operator, operator-keyword

I want know how to represent the C++ new() operator using UML Class Diagram. For example, if I have:

```
Class B
{
  ...
}

Class A
{
  void exampleMethod()
  {
    B *test = new B();
  }
}
```

Comment: is there anything to show in UML regarding this?

Comment: What do you mean by UML? Class diagrams? Sequence diagrams? Activity diagrams? You have to be more specific.

Comment: A class diagram should not be concerned with the code underneath, but a sequence diagram would.

Comment: The class diagram is static.  It should show the relations between classes.  new() is dynamic: it shows the creation of a new object (as shown in the answer of Als)

Comment: Sweet feathery Jesus. If I had to draw UML diagrams, I'd get a McJob.

Answer (score 1):

You can depict it in the following way:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The class diagram is a structural view of the system, so you won't normally see any representation of the behaviour of methods in it.

You can add it as body tag or comment depending on the tool, or associate a sequence diagram containing a «create» message with the method as Als suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Using a class diagram you can use a directed associaton with the stereotype `<<instantiate>>`, see the following example:

[image: class diagram with stereotype]